# Symfony Relationship and Controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, relationship

I'm building a webapp in Symfony where Recruiters can post ads for a job and Candidates apply to them. But I need help to figure out, how can a candidate apply to an ad(or post) with a simple buttton, in this case I used some ManyToMany relationships. If the Candidate press the button there is a method in the main controller that set the user_applied_email and the post_applied_id with all the values. But I don't understand how to do that and what to put in the controller (if it is correct).

PostController :

```
#[Route('/annonce')]
class AnnonceController extends AbstractController
{
#[Route('/', name: 'app_annonce_index', methods: ['GET'])]
public function index(AnnonceRepository $annonceRepository): Response
{
        return $this->render('annonce/index.html.twig', [
            'annonces' => $annonceRepository->findBy(['is_verified' => true]),
        ]);

}

#[Route('/postuler', name: 'app_annonce_postuler', methods: ['GET'])]
public function postuler(Request $request): Response
{

    // getProfileCandidat->setPostApplied()
    // getAnnonce->setUserAppliedEmail()



    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_annonce_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
}

#[Route('/new', name: 'app_annonce_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new(Request $request, AnnonceRepository $annonceRepository): Response
{
    $annonce = new Annonce();
    $form = $this->createForm(AnnonceType::class, $annonce);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_annonce_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('annonce/new.html.twig', [
        'annonce' => $annonce,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}

#[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_annonce_show', methods: ['GET'])]
public function show(Annonce $annonce): Response
{
    if (!$annonce->getIsVerified()) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }
    return $this->render('annonce/show.html.twig', [
        'annonce' => $annonce,
    ]);
    }
```

Also here is the idea of the database (maybe it is correct?) :
[database_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO0TP.png)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have a User entity and use roles (normal, recruiter etc) to determine what they can do. Have a AppliedTo entity as a OneToMany relation (one User can have many AppliedTo). When a User applies to a posting you can use *addAppliedTo* method. Just an idea..

Comment: Ok, thank you, I create an entity like you said, and when the button is clicked it is going to the path that create the entity and so apply to the post, thank you again !